# RegEx for just displaying items in private folder

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I want to have an regular expression witch just allows to access files in a private folder. This is my code so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(.*)(/public/)(.*)
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f #not active in this example
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

It works fine as far as I can see it's working fine but there is one thing I'm wondering about:

if there is an directory structure like `/localhost/test/public` and I'm calling the same url I can see the folder content, but if there isn't a public folder `localhost/test/` and I'm calling `/localhost/test/public` it will lead to the `index.php`

Why isn't it displaying a 404 page?

Comment: if u dont put a slash (/) at the end of an url, the server "thinks" u want a file and checks if it exists, if its a dir it'll automatic use the dir, if not ur rewrite of filename will match and redirect to index.php - if im not wrong

Comment: What do you see if you call `/www/test/nothing`? What status code and page content?

Comment: What URL are you entering in your browser to test this and what is your DocumentRoot?

Comment: The corret url ist `localhost/test/public` sorry about that. If I try `localhost/test/nothing` it displays the index.php just like excepted, there is also no difference between `/public` and `/public/` it looks like the latest slash gets autocompleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think UnskilledFreak is right:

> If you don't put a slash (/) at the end of an url, the server "thinks" you want a file and checks if it exists. If its a directory, it'll automatic use that; if not, your rewrite of filename will match and redirect to index.php